# Schematic "my-comp" cannot resolve the factory

Tags: angular-schematics

I'm following this book: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/schematics-sample

When I execute my schematics

`schematics .:my-comp`

I get the following error:

```
An error occured:
Error: Schematic "my-comp" cannot resolve the factory.
    at NodeModulesEngineHost.createSchematicDescription (/home/.../.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/file-system-engine-host-base.js:174:19)
    at SchematicEngine.createSchematic (/home/.../.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:219:38)
    at CollectionImpl.createSchematic (/home/.../.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:69:29)
    at NodeWorkflow.execute (/home/.../.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/workflow/base.js:99:38)
    at main (/home/.../.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics.js:202:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/.../.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics.js:293:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
```

This is part of my factory:

```
    export default function myComp(options: IFlexComponentOptions): Rule {
  return (host: Tree, context: SchematicContext) => {
    console.log("options before sanatize", options);
    ...
    return rule(host, context);
  };
}
```

my collectyion.json

```
{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/collection-schema.json",
  "schematics": {
    "my-comp": {
      "description": "This schematics generate an Angular Component on the current module or in an specified one",
      "factory": "./my-comp/index#myComp"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, from `export default function myComp` remove the `default`. And it should work. I follow the same book. Lots of incompatibilities.

Comment: It has to do with how the `collections.json` file references the factory - if you have the function exported as default, you do not need the `#helloWorld` in the factory reference. If you do keep the hash, that will be the name of the exported function, in this case, `helloWorld`, and if it was exported default that function name doesn't exist. So to reference the default export, do not include hash on the `collection.json` factory property, and with no default export, you need the hash to identify which exported function to reference.

Answer (score 2):

For those who doesn't use  `default` and has the same issue, please check the hash name versus the function name in the index file.

Comment: That catch was exactly what I needed. Thanks again!